# Vertically align text in div with fixed width and float

Tags: html, css, css-float

I have a situation where I need to vertically align text inside a div that has:

1. A fixed width
2. Multiple lines of text
3. A float applied

Here is an example of using display:table-cell; which won't work because there is no float, which I need:

```
CSS:

.noFloat {
    width:200px; 
    height:200px; 
    border:1px solid black; 
    vertical-align:middle; 
    display:table-cell;
}



HTML:

<div class="noFloat">
    Here is some content for my div. Here is some more content for my div.
</div>
```

Here is an example of using line-height:; which won't work because there are multiple lines of text which ends up being a mess:

```
CSS:

.lineHeight {
    width:200px; 
    height:200px; 
    line-height: 200px;
    border:1px solid black;
}



HTML:

<div class="lineHeight">
    Here is some content for my div. Here is some more content for my div.
</div>
```

Here is an example of using display:table-cell; with a float which won't work because of the float, which aligns everything at the top:

```
CSS:

.withFloat {
    width:200px; 
    height:200px; 
    border:1px solid black; 
    vertical-align:middle; 
    display:table-cell;
    float: left;
}


HTML:

<div class="withFloat">
    Here is some content for my div. Here is some more content for my div.
</div>
```

Here are all 3 examples: http://jsfiddle.net/BJGh5/3/

Comment: Is using a wrapper div an option?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you will need to set a container div.  One to vertically align and one to float.

Comment: I was digging for an answer while the obvious was staring me right in the face. Thanks!